# What is OpenCV's equivalent in EmguCV .at<uchar>(cy, cx)?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I'm new in c++ and opencv, my familiar language is c#.
Found some kind of code and in this code has a line:

```
dst.at<uchar>(cy, cx) = 255;
```

Where dst is destination image, in C# is `Image<Gray, Byte>`. As I understood from a line in this byte writes some color.

Does anyone can explain me this line and which equivalent for it in emgucv?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726) seems to do a fairly good job, IMHO. Since you're new to OpenCV, it may be prudent to familiarize yourself with it and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is used to change the pixel intensity.

Here it is the gray intensity I guess.

try this;

```
Image<Gray,Byte> imageGray; // Assume you have this Object
imageGray[x, y] = new Gray(255);
```

For grayscale it seems order is x ,y only .... But for color it seems the order is y,x.

Search for   ***grayscale image***

in http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images